# Filter Bluetooth Device by Service GUID in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, bluetooth, serial-port

I have the following Bluetooth Device

[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I create a Uwp **DeviceWatcher** that only returns device with Devices with a specific Service Guid, as shown in the picture.
Or are there other possibilities like filter the devices after they are discovered?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: When you use DeviceWatcher to emulate devices, it will return a  `DeviceInformationCollection` containing `DeviceInformation` objects. You could try to get `DeviceInformation.Properties`.  You could check [Device information properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/device-information-properties) and get the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [DeviceWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher?view=winrt-22621) to emulate devices, the result should be a `DeviceInformationCollection` which contains [DeviceInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation?view=winrt-22621) objects. You could access the `DeviceInformation.Properties` Property to check more device proerties like GUID. Please check the available properties here: [Device information properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/device-information-properties)